# make a custom shaped div css html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div with the following shape but with no success
.Here is what i have done 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCVa7/1/)

Here is the code so far.

```
.skew {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:black;    
    height: 120px;
    width: 360px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-11deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-11deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-11deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-11deg);
    transform: skewY(-11deg);
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Any solution is welcomed

Comment: the photos are within the fiddle because for now it does not let me to post photos

Comment: Sounds like an [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) problem.

Comment: it cannot be done with css or html? I dont mind using the photos as background if i put a photo i want to cover only the mark up section.Any help?

Comment: Hmmz, hold on ... why are you trying it in CSS? What's the end-goal here? Covering up what exactly?

Comment: The whole picture to understand it better is that i will upload an image and i want to show only a part of it.The part i want to show has the shape that it is in the fiddle.So i will put the image in the div and will show only the part i want.In the end i just need the div shaped.Also that is the reason why i have put overflow:hidden

Comment: Still vague but better :) How about a png with your figure, and a double layer for your image ... you can contain it with overflow on the parent.

Comment: Can you make me a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

A basic untested approach (if I understood your idea correctly):

HTML:

```
<div class="skew-container">
    <div class="img-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.skew-container { overflow: hidden; background: url(/images/skew.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; height: 175px; width: 484px; }
.img-container { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
.img-container img { width: 100%; }
```

JS:

Now for JavaScript, there's a lot you can do.
But I'm not sure if you'd like to move one of the two images around.
Take a look at my little dice game. How far down the rabbit hole are you willing to go?
http://jsfiddle.net/tive/GcDAb/

The approach shown in the example is a large image with all the dice values and colors.
Moving the image is mathematical, like a matrix, using `background-position` to CSS. A little browser inconsistent but still doable.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for.The problem is that the image must cover only and all the mark up area.Any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about a shoe tv? Create a png, give it a background color, draw your shoe in it and make it transparent. No need for JS that way.

Comment: The mark up area is the middle part of the shoe.It is not the whole shoe that is why i need a div with that shape

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 3D & perspective in your test :

```
body {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective:50px;
}
```

with help from a pseudo, you can do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/FCVa7/3/

Needs to be tuned to your needs ....

but **best is look at SVG to make your shapes and then you can style them from style sheet**